# Keeps String values separated in Android Resources

Tags: android, resources

As you know you can write whatever resource you need inside `res/values`.
I made an xml file for each gui/activity I'm using. Here's an example:

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">This is home!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Hattrick4Manager</string>
    <string name="oauth_button">Authorize me!</string>
    <string name="download_button">Syncronize</string>
    <string name="oauth_name">Authorization</string>
</resources>
```

update-ui.xml

```
<resources>
        <string name="inizio_download">Update Started...</string>
        <string name="fine_download">Update Completed...</string>
        <string name="update_title">Update</string>
        <string name="update_done">Done</string>
        <string name="update_inizio_club">Club...</string>
        <string name="update_inizio_arena">Arena...</string>
        <string name="update_inizio_fan">Fans...</string>
        <string name="update_inizio_matches">Matches...</string>
        <string name="update_inizio_league">League...</string>
        <string name="update_inizio_leaguefix">League Fixtures...</string>
        <string name="update_inizio_economy">Economy...</string>
        <string name="update_inizio_players">Players...</string>
</resources>
```

When I use this in the code I have to recall them like:

```
R.string.update_done
```

or

```
R.string.hello
```

my problem is that like this I have basically to add the prefix for every GUI I make. I would prefer doing something like:

```
R.string.update-ui.done
```

Is it possible?

Comment: No answer, just a question. What should happen if the text "Done" does exist on several activities? Do you want to put it in dozens of files? And what about the translated text? I don't like your approach. Done is Done. Give it the name done and use it in one central strings.xml. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Well, "Done" could not have different semantics because the word is pretty clear but the way I would like to express "Done" could be different. In my case I have in my update-ui "Done" -> "Update Completed" and I could also have in the arena-ui "Done" -> "Building seats completed"

Comment: I do not understand that. The text is 'Done', right? On both activities? What's the problem? If you need to create different semantics use name="updatecompleted" with text="Done" and name="buildingseatscompleted" with text "Done". It's an old discussion what label to use. I prefer to use the label close to the text and not close to the activity/package/...

Comment: I'm sorry I was thinking about the label "Done", not the text inside it. Of course I do not want to do that for redundancy, I want to do that to keep labels separated when I'm programming. To me it's more natural to write R.string.update-ui.done instead of R.string.update_ui_done

Comment: Just to add something. If I have a label done="Done" then that would go under R.string.general-ui.done, I'm not repeating that twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create as many resource files as you want, but you can not perform the nested name referencing based on the filename: the Android `aapt` tool doesn't support arbitrary nested objects on the generated `R` object.

You might be able to do stuff like this in `update-ui.xml`:

```
<resources>
        <string name="update_ui_inizio_download">Update Started...</string>
        <string name="update_ui_fine_download">Update Completed...</string>
</resources>
```

and then use

```
R.string.update_ui_inizio_download
```

to reference the contents of the file